# Is LocalStorage a HTML5 feature? If so Why is it being supported in IE8 and IE9?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, local-storage

I heard that HTML5 supports from IE10+. But while exploring on LocalStorage, it says it will support from IE6+. Am I missing something?

Comment: IE9 has some HTML5 support.

Comment: Here's some support info: http://caniuse.com/#cats=HTML5

Comment: `.innerHTML` is also an HTML5 feature. Standards adopt existing features. Browser vendors don't sit around and wait for standards boards to come up with features.

Answer (score 3):

> Is LocalStorage a HTML5 feature?

No. It was part of the HTML5 draft for a time, but was spun off into the separate [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) specification.

> But while exploring on LocalStorage, it says it will support from IE6+

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) says IE8+ not IE6+.

> I heard that HTML5 supports from IE10+

HTML 5 is a *big* spec. As far as I know, no browser supports all of it. It isn't worth thinking about "HTML 5" support, only about support for specific features you are interested in.

> But while exploring on LocalStorage, it says it will support from IE6+

Non-standard, proprietary features of browsers sometimes get specified and then standardised. Not everything starts out as a W3C draft before being implemented in browsers.